# Trigger custom script on Samba PDC when I add new users

Tags: execute, samba

I have a script who make backup of my /home/{users folder}/{user} folder by folder in TAR:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "###########################################################################">>/home/{users folder}/Rackbkp.txt
echo "Backup: Usuario $1:\`date\`>>/Rack/\`(date +%Y-%m-%d)\`/racklog.txt">>/home/{users folder}/Rackbkp.txt
echo "star -zcv f=/Rack/\`(date +%Y-%m-%d)\`/$1.tar /home/{users folder}/$1">>/home/usuarios/Rackbkp.txt
echo "Backup: Usuario $1 finalizado con éxito! \`date\`>>/Rack/\`(date +%Y-%m-%d)\`/racklog.txt">>/home/usuarios/Rackbkp.txt
```

All I wanna do is trigger this script just after the

```
add user script = /usr/sbin/useradd %u
```

Samba smb.conf line is executed. This scripts appends the newly created user to the backup list so the next time the Backup script is executed we have it's tar file for sure.